# Gaming Meta Login Issue

Tags: support, bug, meta, login

I am seemingly unable to login to meta at the moment.  I try clicking login:

[image]

The page seems to refresh.  I go click on signup, it takes me away from meta, and logs me on:

[image]

If I try logging in again, I have no luck because it just asks me to add a login:

[image]

I appear to have a session where I'm logged in on the normal forum, but not on the meta.  Considering the login in on normal, I am thus not able to "relogin" using normal methods.  I decide to log out, then maybe it'll reset my session:

[image]

But I go back to meta, and I see the annoying login button that isn't working:

[image]

So I decide I have to go clever.  I logout of my normal account (we'll call them separate things...), go back to meta, definitely logged out.  Press the login button, and hey!  Now it works :).  I press the login button, go through the normal process, get sent back to meta... and I'm not logged in.

How can I login to meta?

Note - Sorry for all the pictures, and if this has come up before, I can't seem to find it.  Also note, attaching bug and support tags - because this seems like both.  If they're meant to be exclusive, I can remove one.

Comment: I had this at one point, it fixed itself quite quickly. What OS / browser is this? And could you tag it with [tag:login] and [tag:meta]?

Comment: Running Windows 7, Chrome Version 41.0.2272.101 m - Had this bug for about a day now.  Doesn't appear to be disappearing.  Also, tagging the question now. @Tim

Comment: use http://, probably https is a problem there. Also, clear your cache. I have already been in such situations like you and @Tim - fixes quite quickly.

Comment: @nicael - That was also my problem. What had happened in my case is I was attempting to transition from my main Google-auth login to a Stack Exchange username/password. So my 'login' on meta got confused. Clearing the entire browser cache and logging in again with Stack Exchange fixed the problem for me